# Set theory venn diagram problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given:
Suppose there are $100$ students who take at least one of the following languages Japanese, Polish and Arabic. $65$ take Japenese; $45$ study Polish; $42$ study Arabic; $12$ take Japense and Arabic, but not Polish; $25$ study Japense and Arabic; $7$ take Polish and Arabic but not Japense. How many take all three?

So I figured out through trial and error that the answer is $4$ but I want to know why my equation isn't giving me the correct answer.

So I had $100=(65-12-25-x)+(42-25-7-x)+(45-12-7-x)+ 25+12+7$ 
then I have $100=196-88-3x$, then $-8=-3x$. Why doesn't my equation give me the solution $4$?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for more information and a faster (but slightly less intuitive) way to solve the problem.

Basically, you have $100$ on the left hand side of your equation, and on the right hand side:

- $(65-12-25-x)$ - Japanese only
- $(42-25-7-x)$ - Polish only
- $(45-12-7-x)$ - Arabic only
- $25$ - Japanese and Arabic only
- $12$ - Japanese and Polish only (I'm guessing there's a typo in your original question)
- $7$ - Polish and Arabic only

The right hand side is missing one group of students, the ones who learn all three languages. Therefore, you must add $x$ to the right hand side of the formula. Once you do, you end up with $-8 = -3x + x = -2x$. Then you get $x = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion-exclusion principle states that for sets $A, B, C$ and universal set $U$:
$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B\cap C| + |A\cap B\cap C|$

In our example and letting $A$ be the set of students studying Japanese, $B$ being the set of those studying Polish, and $C$ being the set of those studying Arabic, plugging in what we know: (Assuming the line reading  "25 study Japense and Arabic" is interpreted to mean 25 study japanese and arabic and either does or doesn't study polish)

$$100 = 65 + 45 + 42 - (12+x) - 25 - (7+x) + x\\100=108 - x\\x=8$$

In the case that it was intended that the line "25 study Japense and Arabic" is intended to read "25 study Japanese and Arabic but not Polish" then we have:

$$100 = 65 + 45 + 42 - (12+x) - (25+x) - (7+x) + x\\100=108 - 2x\\x=4$$

Your error in your calculations I believe is:
$100=(65-12-25-x)+(42-25-7-x)+(45-12-7-x)+ 25+12+7$

you added what is only in A and no others, what is only in B and no others, what is only in C and no others, what is in A and B but not C, what is in A and C but not B, what is in B and C but not A.

$U = A\backslash (B\cup C) + B\backslash(A\cup C) + C\backslash (A\cup B) + (A\cap B)\backslash C + (A\cap C)\backslash B + (B\cap C)\backslash A$

Which would have almost been correct except to make it correct you should also have added $A\cap B\cap C$, what is in all simultaneously.

Making the result: $100=196-88-2x \Rightarrow 2x = 8 \Rightarrow x=4$